# Creating navigation list items with a foreach loop and array

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to use php to output a nav list using a foreach loop, I am having troubles with string conversion.

```
<ul>
            <?php 
            $taco = array("This", "That", "And", "Repeat");

            foreach($taco as $php) {
                print "<li class=\"nav\"><a href=\"# $taco\"> $taco</a><li>";
            }
            ?>
        </ul>
```

How do I add the # in the href without screwing with the variable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your foreach doesn't make sense, you should definitely read more about arrays and loops.

You're trying to print your entire array twice on every line, you should print the actual element at the current state of the loop instead.

As for your printing issue...stop printing HTML then....do this:

```
<ul>
    <?php $tacos = array("This", "That", "And", "Repeat"); ?>

    <?php foreach ($tacos as $taco) : ?>

        <li class="nav">
            <a href="#<?php echo $taco; ?>"><?php echo $taco; ?></a>
        </li>

    <?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>
```

Putting your whole HTML in an echo is a bad practice.

You should read up on all of this:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: No problem. The alternative syntax is very useful, it'll also help in your editors as your code will appear in HTML and be colored, which it wouldn't be if it was within an echo.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the **array** to output the value. `$php` contains your **value**:

```
foreach($taco as $php) {
    print "<li class=\"nav\"><a href=\"#{$php}\"> {$php}</a></li>";
}
```

**Edit:** I often prefer to use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) to output this kind of statement. Each their own, but here's a nice way to do that:

```
$tag = '<li class="nav"><a href="#%s">%s</a></li>';
foreach($taco as $php) {
    print sprintf($tag, $php, $php);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `foreach` is:

```
foreach($array as $element)
```

So this will work:

```
$taco = array("This", "That", "And", "Repeat");

foreach($taco as $taco_elem) {
     print "<li class=\"nav\"><a href=\"#$taco_elem\">$taco_elem</a></li>";
}
```